# State is not updating in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am fetching an API and setting response data in the products array. But, the products array state is not updating and returning an empty array.
here is my code,

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const apiCaller = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:2000/');
            const pro = await res.data;
            setProducts(pro);
            console.log(products);
         }
        apiCaller();
    }, []);
```

I have tried passing the 'products ' in the dependency array but that results in infinite renders.

Comment: This should work. The reason you don't see `products` updated in `console.log(products)` is that the updated value is avilable at next render. console.log `pro` instead of `products`.

Comment: There is also no need to `await` the value of `res.data`, it's not a Promise/thenable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1):

the reason you can not see the value because the firrst log in inside the async funtion is getting the previous state of products is [] and setProduct is also an async and its updates will not be reflected immediately inside the same render cycle you will see the updated product out side the useEffect

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const apiCaller = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:2000/');
        const pro = res.data;
        setProducts(pro);
    };
    apiCaller();
}, []);

// This will log the updated value of products whenever it changes
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(products);
}, [products]);

// You can do this also 
console.log(products);
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to map the products array objects. And there it is not showing any thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an empty product array as the state gets updated after the **useEffect** is unmounted.

So instead of printing product inside **useEffect** try to write outside it.

```
     const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);


     useEffect(() => {
            const apiCaller = async () => {
                const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:2000/');
                const pro = await res.data;
                setProducts(pro);
             }
            apiCaller();
        }, []);
      console.log(products);
```

If you want to map it after the data you receive you can do it like below inside useEffect:

```
const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:2000/');

    const pro = await res.data;
    pro.map((product,index)=>{
       //// do the action here
    })
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to map the products array objects. And there it is not showing any thing.